# How to navigate through modal pages in Xamarin.Forms using Fresh.MVVM

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

I was trying to push a modal page in my xamarin forms app using MVVM when pressing a button. I already know how to use navigation stacks, but no idea how to do it with content pages as modal pages, I have tried multiple things, especially, calling the PushPageModel method.

This is the last thing I have tried:
View or Page:

```
<Label
                x:Name="forgottenPasswordLabel"
                Text="Forgot password?"
                TextColor="LightPink"
                FontSize="16"
                FontAttributes="Bold"

                VerticalOptions="Start"
                HorizontalOptions="End"
                Margin="25,0,25,25">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ForgotPasswordCommand}"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

ViewModel class:

```
public class LogInViewModel : FreshBasePageModel
    {
        public ICommand ForgotPasswordCommand { get; set; }

        public LogInViewModel()
        {
        }

        public override void Init(object initData)
        {
            ForgotPasswordCommand = new Command (async() =>
            {
                var newPage = FreshPageModelResolver.ResolvePageModel<ForgottenPasswordViewModel>();
                await CoreMethods.PushPageModel<ForgottenPasswordViewModel>(null, false, true);
            }); 
        }
    }
```

App.xaml.cs class:

```
public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = FreshPageModelResolver.ResolvePageModel<LogInViewModel>();
        }
```

This code gives the following error: "FreshTinyIoC.TinyIoCResolutionException: 'Resolve failed: IFreshNavigationService"

And that is all, if you need more information I will provide it as soon as I see your request, thank you all for your time, hope you have a great day.

Edit: Stack trace requested:

> at FreshTinyIoC.FreshTinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal (FreshTinyIoC.FreshTinyIoCContainer+TypeRegistration registration, FreshTinyIoC.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, FreshTinyIoC.ResolveOptions options) [0x000f7] in C:"Here goes the path" 
>     at FreshTinyIoC.FreshTinyIoCContainer.Resolve (System.Type resolveType, System.String name) [0x00000] in C:\"Here goes the path"
>     at FreshTinyIoC.FreshTinyIoCContainer.Resolve[ResolveType] (System.String name) [0x00000] in C:"Here goes the path"
>     at FreshMvvm.FreshTinyIOCBuiltIn.Resolve[ResolveType] (System.String name) [0x00000] in C:"Here goes the path"
>     at FreshMvvm.PageModelCoreMethods.PushPageModelWithPage (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, FreshMvvm.FreshBasePageModel pageModel, System.Object data, System.Boolean modal, System.Boolean animate) [0x00177] in C:"Here goes the path"
>     at FreshMvvm.PageModelCoreMethods.PushPageModel (FreshMvvm.FreshBasePageModel pageModel, System.Object data, System.Boolean modal, System.Boolean animate) [0x00048] in C:"Here goes the path"
>     at FreshMvvm.PageModelCoreMethods.PushPageModel[T] (System.Object data, System.Boolean modal, System.Boolean animate) [0x00040] in C:"Here goes the path" 
>     at FirstApp.ViewModels.LogInViewModel.b__5_0 () [0x0003a] in D:\"Here goes the path"

Comment: From what I understand through the exception is that there is something in your `ForgottenPasswordViewModel` or View that is causing this issue, Something there could be throwing an exception or you have not followed the folder structure or `FreshMVVM` now to make it easier for us to understand this you will have to add the Stracktrace for this exception here!

Comment: @FreakyAli how do I get the stack trace for an exception

Comment: Add a try-catch block in the catch block when an exception is thrown the exception object contains your StackTrace! If you have exceptions this is the best place to start looking for the issue!

Comment: @FreakyAli I updated this question with the StackTrace!

Comment: It's failing to find an instance of IFreshNavigationService, so I don't think you've initialized FreshMVVM correctly. At some point, TinyIOC needs to be told how to instantiate the navigation service. I doubt that it's working with non-modal pages either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a misunderstanding of concepts, I thought that a content page and a navigation page were two different types of pages, like a tabbed page, master detailed page, carousel page, and content page. So I was trying not to use the following code thinking that FreshNavigationContainer forced me to use a navigation page and not a content page, which is true but not completely, because yes, it forces you to use a navigation page, but you are also using a content page, since navigation page is a property of content page, so as I said it was all a misunderstanding of concepts :

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var thePage = FreshPageModelResolver.ResolvePageModel<LogInViewModel>();
            MainPage = new FreshNavigationContainer(thePage);
        }
}
```

I didn't say this on the question, but the purpose of all of this was to not see a bar at the top of the screen, which now I understand that because a navigation page and a content page are not 2 different things, you can do it in the page.xaml with:

```
<ContentPage NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
```